# What is the difference between Sahne and Rahm?

Tags: synonym, regional

I was taught that cream is "Sahne" (f) in Scandinavian school German lessons, however, when visiting Switzerland, it appeared to be called "Rahm" (m).

I tried asking about this, and the person didn't seem to understand "Sahne", but that could be my German being rusty.

Is it a North/South/regional difference or is it subtly different creams, different fat content etc.? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your hunch re. regionalism is correct.

In most parts of Germany, *cream* is *Sahne*, Swiss German uses *Rahm*, so does Swabia<sup>1</sup> and South Bavaria<sup>2</sup>, Austria calls it *Obers*.

Now as you probably expected, this is too simple. (Sweet) Cream comes in two varieties: liquid and whipped. And the linguistic Rahm-Sahne-border is not the same for both preparations, at last in SW-Germany. Born and raised with a Swabian dialect, the liquid cream for me is *Rahm*, if it's whipped, it turns into *Sahne* - without any qualifier like "Schlag-". Northern Germany distinguishes between *Sahne* (-> liquid) and *Schlagsahne* (-> whipped). Likewise for Switzerland (*Schlagrahm*) and Austria (*Schlagobers*).

And once you realized that Sahne and Rahm are the same stuff, it becomes clear that a *Rahmsoße* and a *Sahnesoße* both indicate a preparation refined with cream. Easy, right?

---

<sup>1</sup> I tried to find details about the distribution in the Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache, unfortunately without success. Input from other comunity members is very welcome.

<sup>2</sup> Altbayern, i.e. Upper Bavaria, Lower Bavaria and the Oberpfalz.

Comment: To me, _Schlagsahne_ is sweet cream even when not whipped (as opposed to _saure Sahne_).

Comment: In Dutch, *room* is both single cream and double cream (for whipping), but rarely whipped cream, while *slagroom* is both double cream (cream for whipping) and whipped cream, but not single cleam. So the terms overlap, and neither includes the other.

Comment: @reinierpost Yes, in English it's so bewildering that if my wife sends me shopping and writes down "cream", I'm going to be on the phone asking **which one**, while quietly sobbing in front of the shelf. ;)

Comment: Aaaaalllright! Aparently this neds more clarification re. culinary terms. I had originally focussed on Rahm vs. Sahne, but will do an extensive edit later tonight or  tomorrow.

Comment: Yes that seems the right difference, for the liquid Cream. In Austria seems to be Obers, in Switzerland Rahm, in Germany Sahne. However as I knew in Switzerland they use also Creme, e.g. Kaffee-creme, Kaffee-rahm, it taks sometimes words from french.

Comment: @GiaRui Just be careful with Café Crème in Switzerland - that's actually often black coffee, prepared similar to a very long Espresso, also named Schümli (referring to the crema on a propper espresso drink). It *may* also be served with cream, then "crème" stands for the French term.

Comment: With "Schlagobers" in Austrian, it's actually a bit more difficult, I think, as the border seems not to be so strict between the meanings "whipped" and "fluid": I think in spoken language, I mostly use it for the fluid variant, too, and apparently [others](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=schlagobers&t=canonical&iax=1&ia=images) do the same. Probably the word is commonly interpreted as "cream for whipping" instead of "whipped cream" (like in "salad oil", but with more ambiguous pragmatics).

Comment: Auch in Altbayern ist es *Schlagrahm* und *Sauerrahm*, wobei *Schlagsahne* oft noch für die aufgeschlagene Variante existiert.

Comment: And just to make it even more complex, one can also order cake or coffee "mit Schlag", i.e. whipped cream - at least in the south. This at least solves the problem of whether to call it "Sahne", "Rahm" or "Obers" ;)

Comment: @Stephie In contrast to the North-South divide for _Sahne_ and _Rahm,_ to word in East Frisian Low German is _Rohm_ (e.g. used for the famous tea East Frisian tea ceremony).

Comment: In Switzerland, *Schlagrahm* is cream that can be whipped or has been whipped. *Geschlagener Rahm* is always whipped cream. *Rahm* can be all of that and "non-whippable" cream as well, sometimes called *Halbrahm* because it's low-fat. A *Café Crème* is a long espresso served with *Kafferahm* (coffee creamer). *Crema* is what @Stephie is refering to as *Schümli*, using the Italian word, and though the word in Italian means cream, it is used to express foam, because coffee foam is creamy.

Comment: And we were taught that Schlagsahne is whipped (beaten!) cream, so at least that is consistent with the Northern dialects. Wow, I am used to simple shopping there, two grades: "kaffefløde" - coffee cream or single or low fat cream and "piskefløde" - whipping cream or double or full fat cream. Thank you! While not really able to judge, I will just mark this comprehensive answer/comments as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Answers might differ for different Regions in Germany. In my locality (SW Germany), *Sahne* is a linguistic import from Hochdeutsch. Traditionally, *Rahm* was used for both the fluid in the dairy farm that swims on top of the fresh milk and the fluid in the kitchen used to cook from and/or whip. The linguistic newcomer *Sahne* has, apparently, extruded *Rahm* from any "kitchen" use (and we use the same term for both single and double cream in the kitchen).

With my friends on the dairy farm, the same thing is still *Rahm*.